# How to evaluate this definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here is the integral we have to evaluate:

> $$\int_0^4\sqrt{x^2+4}\,dx+\int_2^{2\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{x^2-4}\,dx$$

After observing, i realise that i can't evaluate these integrals from area of circle, I say that $u=\sqrt{x^2+4}$. Then i can say $dx=\frac{udu}{\sqrt{u^2-4}}$. The first term would transform into:
$$\int_2^{2\sqrt{5}}\frac{u^2\,du}{\sqrt{u^2-4}}$$
Similarly i say $v=\sqrt{x^2-4}$. Then i can also say $dx=\frac{vdv}{\sqrt{v^2+4}}$ and the second term would transform into:
$$\int_0^4\frac{v^2\,dv}{\sqrt{v^2+4}}$$
But this integrals also doesn't seem easy to solve. It goes without saying  that after substitution, the bounds of integrals interchanged. Maybe it can be helpful to solve the problem. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Yes. It leads a very long solution in view of the fact that we have two integrals to solve. In addition to this we have to plug our bounds.

Comment: I suspect there's a typo: If the upper limit in the second integral is changed to $2 \sqrt{2}$, then the regions whose areas are represented by the two integrals have a simple, special relationship. In particular, calculus is not needed to evaluate the sum of those areas.

Comment: If that upper limit is correct as stated (which would make for a real red herring), then there is no particular fast method for evaluating the first integral, as the indefinite integral is equivalent under the suggested trigonometric substitution to $\int \sec^3 \theta \,d\theta$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed .

Comment: As an alternative--if the limits are correct--note that you can combine the two integrals after your first transformation into $$\int_2^{2\sqrt5}\frac{2u^2-4}{\sqrt{u^2-4}}\,du$$ by making the substitution $x=u$ in the second integral. This may not do much for you, but it's worth noting. Similarly, you could use your second substitution and combine the integrals into $$\int_0^4\frac{2v^2+4}{\sqrt{v^2+4}}\,dv.$$

Comment: What will going to happen if we assume the upper limit is $2\sqrt{2}$? What is the relationship that you've mentioned? @Travis

Comment: @AbdullahUYU Plotting the regions yourself would be most instructive, I think.

Comment: Your advice caused me to solve the problem but there is no typo about upper limit @Travis

Comment: @AbdullahUYU Ah, you're right, I'd miscomputed something myself when I commented before. At any rate, I'm glad you found my comment helpful, and +1 to your fine answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+4}$ and $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x^2-4}$. Note that
$$f(4)=2\sqrt{5} \\
f(0)=2
$$
We know that the integral of an inverse function can be calculated with

> $$\int_{f(k)}^{f(l)}f^{-1}(x)\,dx=lf(l)-kf(k)-\int_k^lf(x)\,dx$$

So the integral
$$\int_0^4\sqrt{x^2+4}\,dx+\int_2^{2\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{x^2-4}\,dx$$
can be written as
$$\int_0^4\sqrt{x^2+4}\,dx+4\cdot2\sqrt{5}-2\cdot0-\int_0^4\sqrt{x^2+4}\,dx$$
Finally the result is
$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
8\sqrt{5}
}
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: for the first integral use Integration by parts, $$u'=1,v=\sqrt{x^2+4}$$
for the second integral use $$x=\cosh(t)$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a trigonometric substitution in this case. Let me demonstrate it for the first integral.

let $x= 2\tan u$ and $dx= 2\sec^2 u du$. Applying this substitution on the integral $$\int_0^4 \root \of{x^2+4} dx$$
yields

$$\int_0^{\arctan 0.5}4sec^3u du$$

You can solve the integral above by using integration by parts

The same idea applies to your second integral but the use of $x = 2\sec u$ as a subsitution would be more appropiate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

1.) $\int \sqrt{x^2+a^2} = \frac 12 x \sqrt{x^2+a^2} - \frac{a^2}2 sinh^{-1}\frac xa + c$

Or

$= \frac 12 x \sqrt{x^2+a^2} + \frac{a^2}2 \ln|x + \sqrt{x^2+a^2}+c$

2.) $\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2} = \frac 12 x \sqrt{x^2-a^2} - \frac{a^2}2 cosh^{-1}\frac xa + c$

Or

$= \frac 12 x \sqrt{x^2-a^2} - \frac{a^2}2 \ln|x + \sqrt{x^2-a^2} + c$

For more formulas [See this link.](http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/math-results-and-formulas/formulas-of-integration.html)

After applying these formulas fill limits.

Answer (score 0):

HINT...for the first one substitute $x=2\sinh \theta$ and for the second substitute $x=2\cosh \theta$